#  what's the "mapping" between audio analog input(voltage) and digital data for microphone?

Tags: android, audio

i want to realize 232 communication over Audio jack in Android phone.  >i met a problem when i want to convert the audio voltage to digital data,   i don't know what's the digital value that a audio voltage will be convert to , in other word it's refer to the "mapping" between audio analog and digital data;

thanks !

Comment: I guess you have to figure out the lower and upper limits dynamically for each phone

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard mapping between volts and "digits". With pro gear, several standards have been proposed. I have most often calibrated at 0 dBu = -10 dBFS, but a lot of (by no means all!) modern pro analog gear is pretty linear well above +10 dBu, so I'm not sure that calibration makes sense.

The mapping is defined by each individual A/D converter chip and effected by associated electronic circuitry which may add or subtract signal gain. In principle, a given A/D converter will convert its complete input analog range (whatever that is) to it's complete output range (whatever that is). If I remember correctly (which I may not) several popular 16-bit analog devices A/D converters range +/- 2.2 V, while others can operate in different ranges depending on what is supplied. In the 2.2 V case, that would mean that 0V in is close to digital 0, +2.2 V is close to digital 32767 and -2.2 V is close to digital 32768. I say "close to" both because of the obvious asymmetry on the digital side, and the not-so-obvious effects of temperature, noise, frequency and so on.

Once the signal is converted from Volts to "digits" by hardware, it may be further converted to floating point representation by software. There is no standard way this is done either. See: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2009/12/int-float-int-its-jungle-out-there.html At least the various methods get it close.

Comment: hi...Roche, i made a test, when the Mic of my Android Phone was input  a constant 2.2v continuously , the converted digits in the phone  jumped to a big number 32767  then fail to numbers around zero immediately,even the voltage was still input. could you help me  ... appreciated!

Comment: The A/D converter and surrounding circuitry is designed to pass alternating current, not direct current. For the test you are trying to perform to work, you should pass a sine wave of, perhaps, 1 kKz and known peak-to-peak voltage. Also, if you are interested in a particular device, you can often find specifications online.

Comment: Thanks ,Dear Roche , the reason why does inputting direct currect not work is that the microphone is AC-coupled

Comment: @BjornRoche +1 for nice answer, but one should mention that there are at least two A/D types; AC-coupled and DC-coupled. AC-coupled A/D will pass altering current, effectively filtering DC noise. DC-coupled however is in almost one-to-one relation, but may get saturated if some DC creeps int.

Comment: There are many many things I left out in my answer, the important thing in answering this question is to clarify that while the connection between input voltage and digital output is (or should be) linear, it is not guaranteed to be set to any particular scale.